# How Message reads value by taking LPTSTR variable as parameters in visual c++?

Tags: visual-c++, memory-management, shared-memory, file-mapping

I tried an example from MSDN that shows how to read and write using fileMapping functions. I am pasting the code here for you reference from MSDN. The link is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx

```
#include"stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include<iostream>
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")
using namespace std;
#define BUF_SIZE 256
TCHAR szName[]=TEXT("/Global/MyFileMappingObject");

int _tmain()
{
   HANDLE hMapFile;
   LPTSTR pBuf;

   hMapFile = OpenFileMapping(
                   FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,   // read/write access
                   FALSE,                 // do not inherit the name
                   szName);               // name of mapping object

   if (hMapFile == NULL)
   {
      _tprintf(TEXT("Could not open file mapping object\n"),
             GetLastError());
        //cout<<"Could not create file mapping object"<<endl;
       _getche();

      return 1;
   }

   pBuf = (LPTSTR) MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, // handle to map object
               FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,  // read/write permission
               0,
               0,
               BUF_SIZE);

   if (pBuf == NULL)
   {
      _tprintf(TEXT("Could not map view of file (%d).\n"),
             GetLastError());
       //cout<<"Could not map view of file"<<endl;
       _getche();
      CloseHandle(hMapFile);

      return 1;
   }
   //_tprintf(Text("Message from process 1 is %s",&pBuf));

   //Convert LPTSTR to char
   cout<<"Pbuf is "<<*pBuf<<endl;
   size_t size = wcstombs(NULL,pBuf,0);
   const wchar_t* charStr = new wchar_t[size+1];
   //wcstombs(pBuf,charStr,size+1);

   MessageBox(NULL, pBuf, TEXT("Process2"), MB_OK);

   UnmapViewOfFile(pBuf);

   CloseHandle(hMapFile);

   _getche();
   return 0;
}
```

if you see there is this statement MessageBox(NULL, pBuf, TEXT("Process2"), MB_OK);
that takes in pBuf (LPCTSTR variable) and prints what was entered in the file. 
I want to retrieve what pBuf points to or can somebody guide how messagebox can read the value.
I tried using *pBuf but it gives me some location. I am just stuck here. Please help.

Comment: What does `cout<<"Pbuf is "<< (LPCTSTR)pBuf << endl;` give you?

Comment: I used cout<<"Pbuf is "<<(LPCSTR)pBuf<<endl;     and the out put was the 1st letter of the whole number..e.g. if I had stored 630 I saw "Pbuf is 6" and when I was storing 152 I saw "Pbuf is 1".

Answer (score 0):

1. You are using `OpenFileMapping()` without `CreateFileMapping()`. So, `hMapFile` is null.
2. Even if, you use `CreateFileMapping()`, unless writing something to MapFile, your `pBuf` is always empty in your code.

Below code is just sample. I hope this will help you a little.

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        HANDLE hFile, hMap;
        char *data;
        DWORD written_size;

        //create text file for test
        hFile = CreateFile(L"test.txt",GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 
            NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

        //and write "123" on file
        WriteFile(hFile, "123", 3,  &written_size, NULL);

        //create file map
        hMap = CreateFileMapping(
            hFile,                          //file handle
            NULL,
            PAGE_READWRITE,
            0,                           //file size
            0,                           //file size
            NULL);                    //map name
        if(hMap == NULL)
        {
            cout << "CreateFileMapping() fail";
            CloseHandle(hFile);
            return 1;
        }

        //file link to map
        data = (char *)MapViewOfFile(hMap, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 0);

        //MessageBox prints "123"
        //Notice that using 'MessageBoxA' for output 'char *'.
        MessageBoxA(NULL, data, "Process2", MB_OK);

        UnmapViewOfFile(data);
        CloseHandle(hMap);
        CloseHandle(hFile);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I have put a link about MSDN. I have created another program that writes to the file. In this code pasted above I need to read from pBuf or the LPCTSTR. I am able to read the 1st letter but am trying to find how do I read the whole number

Comment: it is LPCSTR and not LPCTSTR. I am missing something.